# IF statement is not running inside SWITCH statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

Im trying to put IF statement inside each case from Switch statement. somehow my IF code does not running. here is the image of my code

[If statement inside Switch for case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k05ha.png)

the toast inside case:0 is running and showing output, however the IF is not running. 
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Post the code above, not the image

Comment: Also, use `equals` for `String` comparisons, not `==`. You're even getting warnings for that.

Comment: And please tell what the toast intends to do

Comment: You can see your IDE has highlighted the == in you expressions and it will have a warning that perhaps you shouldn't ignore. ;)

Comment: Replace your code with below code portion  
        case 0:
                if (setHadithLanguage.equals("malay")) {
                    //write code
                } else if (setHadithLanguage.equals("english")) {
                    //write code
                }

Comment: i just put the toast just to see if there is any value inside setHadithLanguage. and yes it have

Comment: YESS, the .equals() is working. Thankyou guy.. MUWAHHH